# How do I modify the D3.js script to show my json's (contains SAP CDS Views) data correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I have the following code for visualizing a network of cds views from a json. If I change the ticked function from return d.source.x; to d.SourceViewName.x and d.TargetViewName.x (and ys) it still does not work. Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }
  
  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.SourceViewName;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  d3.json("data/summarized.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return d.target_minimum_cardinality * 3;
      });

    var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.CDSViewPackage);
      })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.SourceViewName;
      });

    simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        }) // - ll -
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        }) //should this be d.TargetViewName.x ?
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        }); // - ll -
      node
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        });
    }
  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;

  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
</script>
```

My json file that cointains SAP cds views that looks like this:

```
"nodes": [
  {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "some example id",
      "uri": "some example uri",
      "type": "some example type
    },
    "SourceViewName": "SourceViewName1",
    "ApplicationComponent": "AppComponent1",
    "ApplicationComponentName": "AppCpName",
    "CDSViewPackage": "packagename",
    "to_edges": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "to_edges uri"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "id2",
      "uri": "some uri 2",
      "type": "type 2"
    },
    "SourceViewName": "SourceViewName2",
    "ApplicationComponent": "appcmpt2",
    "ApplicationComponentName": "cmptname2",
    "CDSViewPackage": "package2",
    "to_edges": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "to edges uri 2"
      }
    }
  }
```

and the "links" :

```
"links": [

  {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "id1",
      "uri": "uri1",
      "type": "type1"
    },
    "SourceViewName": "srcvw1",
    "AssociationName": "assocname",
    "TargetViewName": "targetname",
    "target_minimum_cardinality": 1,
    "target_maximum_cardinality": 1,
    "ApplicationComponentName": "appcmpt1"
  }, ...
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SourceViewName in your Node data does not appear to match your SourceViewName in Link data.  In Links your SourceViewName should be "SourceViewName1", and your TargetViewName should be "SourceViewName2"  It appears your code is searching for srcvw1.x, but there is no node with that name or id.